# Using Pivot in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate-functions, window-functions

Here is the link of the question.

[Hackerrank occupations problem link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations/problem)

I'm new to sql and this community. So in advance; I'm sorry if this is too basic stuff or my query is too messy.

Anyway, I think solution is to pivot the data. I wrote a query but it didn't work. Here is my work;

```
Select [Doctor],[Profesor], [Singer],[Actor] 
from
(select row_number() over (partition by occupation order by name) [RowNumber], * from occupations ) as ttable
PIVOT
(
max(name) for occupation in ([Doctor],[Profesor],[Singer],[Actor])
)
as pivottable;
```

I couldn't figure out where is the problem in this query. Can you guys enlighten me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. It would help people to answer your question if you told us what you intend the query to do. Otherwise we can't know if it solves your needs. No, I'm not going to click on your link. Explain it in _this post_. Show sample data, and an example of what you want the result to be from your query given that sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use conditional aggregation for this: it is more flexible than `pivot`, is usually portable across databases (as opposed to vendor-specific `pivot`s), and performs at least as well as bespoke syntaxes:

```
select 
    max(case when occupation = 'Doctor'    then name end) as doctor,
    max(case when occupation = 'Professor' then name end) as professor,
    max(case when occupation = 'Singer'    then name end) as singer,
    max(case when occupation = 'Actor'     then name end) as actor
from (
    select o.*,
        row_number() over(partition by occupation order by name) rn
    from occupations o
) o
group by rn
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Max(Case...` aggregate option works great, and i often use it, but you are quite close with your pivot:

```
Select [Doctor],[Professor], [Singer],[Actor] 
from(
    select row_number() over (order by name) [RowNumber], * from Occupations 
) as ttable
PIVOT(
  max(name) for occupation in ([Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor])
)
as pivottable;
```

Just get rid of the partitioning in your window function for calculating row number.